# Iterate folders in an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have below structure in my bucket

```
testing -- bucket name
test/order/text1.txt
test/order/text2.txt
test/order2/abc.txt
test/order3/abc.txt
```

and I want to iterate it like this

```
 testing

     test

      -order

            text1.txt
            text2.txt

     -order2
            abc.txt

     -order3
            abc.txt
```

When I use `listObjectSummary`, it gives me file details not folder details, so can anyone help me how I can get folder details in a bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon doesn't have folders *per se*, it's simply a convenient way to format keys (note that I didn't say "filenames").

This means that you'll have to break apart the keys yourself, to simulate a folder structure. Probably the easiest way to do this in Java is with a hierarchical tree of maps: `TreeMap<String,Map<?>>`.

Comment: Thanks dear, i was thinking the same but someone told me that we can do by folder per se. So Thanks again mate :)